# What's the difference between --host and --target in gcc?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

> There are three system names that the build knows about:  the
>   machine you are building  on (build),  the  machine  that  you are 
>   building  for  (host),  and  the  machine  that  GCC  will  produce 
>   code  for  (target).    When  you  configure  GCC,  you  specify 
>   these  with  ‘--build=’,  ‘--host=’, and ‘--target=’.

Aren't `the machine  that  you are  building  for` and `the  machine  that  GCC  will 
produce  code  for` the same thing? What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference of `./configure` option `--build`, `--host` and `--target`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's possible to build gcc as a cross compiler. That is, you can build a gcc that runs on one architecture (the host) but generates code for a different architecture (the target).

The common place you'll come across this is when building code for embedded platforms. If you're writing code for the processor in your fridge, you'd kind of like to build it on your desktop, not in the fridge!

Some folks use cross compilers to build code for a different OS on the same architecture.  For example, it's possible to target Windows from a Linux host with the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) toolchain.

Comment: so, for the fridge analogy, the host is our desktop and target is the fridge? Pls correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: eh .. came up with this post and just want to say that it seems to be a wrong answer.. If we are preparing gcc as a compiler for the fridge, then host=fridge will be appropriate. I am confused now because there are 7 up votes to this.

Comment: build = where am I compiling the compiler, host = where the compiler will run, target = what code will the compiler produce.  If I am on my desktop building a new compiler that will run on my desktop and generate code for my fridge, then build=desktop, host=desktop, target=fridge.

Answer (score 1):

As per "Configure Terms" the different between "host" and "target" only applies to building a GCC cross compiler for a different machine.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html