# Google test: how to check a global C (C++) function was called

Tags: c++, googletest

I am writing test cases for a scripting language which is embedded in a C (or C++) application and one of the features is that the scripting language calls a method from the "host" program. The entire project is using the google test framework, and down here is one of the tests:

```
TEST(Functions, ExternalCalling)
{
    SCRIPT_START
    "                                      \
    extern void external_callee(int, int); \
    external_callee(1,2);                  \
    "
    SCRIPT_END
}

NAP_EXPORTS
void external_callee(nap_int_t a, nap_int_t b)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\na=%"PRINT_d", b=%"PRINT_d"\n", a, b);
    if(a != 1 || b != 2) FAIL();
}
```

Do not mind the `SCRIPT_START` and `SCRIPT_END` macros, they just create/destroy scripting language objects (`NAP_EXPORTS` is defined as `extern "C"` so that the dynamic library loader can resolve the name).

As you can see the script defines an external method (from the host application) and then calls it. Right now I am sure that the method is called since I can see on the stderr/output the values of `a` and `b` but yeah... this has the feeling of manual testing :) How can I use the google test framework to make sure that the method actually was called without having to look on the screen? (I'd like to avoid hackish solutions, like use a global flag...)

Comment: Are you able to change the signature of `external_callee` to include a `FILE*` instead of hard-coding `stderr`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck not really since there must be a match between the scripting language types (`int`) and the C types (`nap_int_t`).

Comment: If it's plain C, it can get tricky with Google Mocks. Take a look at https://cmocka.org/

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want to do is mock the function.

Look at mocking frameworks like [google-mock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).

The `EXPECT_CALL` macro lets you specify call occurences (with argument filtering).

See also [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552805/using-google-mock-for-c-code) how to create C trampolins to hide C++ interfaces behind C code.

if you also want to have a real result you also might be interested in the `invoke` function that allows you to forward arguments to a real implementation.

the [google mock cookbook](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook) has recipes for all use patterns above.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas, in order from least to most insidious:

1. Make your function return a string instead of printing it internally.  Or return something, at least.
2. Add an (optional) `FILE*` parameter to `external_callee()` and write there instead of hard-coding `stderr`.  Then your test harness can hook it up to a temporary file or something fancier.
3. Make a global variable which is the `FILE*` to write to.  Default it to `stderr` but let the test harness change it.  Basically like the previous idea but without modifying the signature.
4. Have your test harness reopen the stderr file descriptor as a pipe.  Call the function and then try to read from that pipe.
5. Override `printf()` in your test program.  Yes, you can probably do this--try it!  Just define `printf()` yourself with the same signature and that one should get called.  Then you can do anything you want.

Comment: Good ideas but you didn't include the correct/idiomatic/conventional one: mocking `external_callee`.