# What host and target to use when generating config.h for Android with ./configure?

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling

I'm currently using a Windows 7 x64 PC to build an NDK project for Android. I'm compiling the [Tremor](http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/Tremor/) Ogg/Vorbis decoder (and trying out [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) and [RubberBand](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/)/[FFTW3](https://github.com/evan/fftw3)) embedded into a Visual Studio project with [vs-android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/). What I've done is to generate the config.h file with Cygwin and everything seems to be working fine. **But**, I want to make sure the flags I'm passing in are as compatible and optimal as possible.

I understand a bit the differences between the [build host and target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target) flags, but I'm not sure exactly which strings to pass in. *Should host and target take exactly the same strings?*

I've found a few different examples of command lines around the net, but with no explanation of their differences:

```
--host=arm --target=arm-android-linux-uclibcgnueabi

--host=arm-android-linux --target=arm-android-linux

-–target=arm-eabi

--target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=arm-linux-androideabi

arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3 (used in vs-android)
--target=arm-androideabi4.4.3-linux -- host=target=arm-androideabi4.4.3-linux
```

I also have the option of using **./autogen.sh** or **./configure**, which generate a config.h with different options...

Comment: Not a complete answer to your question, but unless you're dealing with a compiler, you shouldn't use --target at all. --target, as explained in the link you provided, allows you to, say, build GCC to run on x86 and cross-compile for arm. Does an Ogg/Vorbis decoder generate any code? If not, --target is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Tremor doesn't use config.h file. So there is no need to run ./configure for tremor. Just include needed .c files in your Android.mk file and you are done.

Take look how google does compiling of Tremor in Android sources. Here's a link to git repository that includes Android.mk file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tremor.git

Btw, in your [blog post](http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2012/01/ogg-vorbis-audio-decoding-on-android-ndk.html) you wrote that Tremor has LGPL license. That is wrong. Tremor has BSD-like license. BSD is much more relaxed terms than LGPL. LGPL basically either requires you to link library as shared, or to make all your project under LGPL. With BSD you can link to library as static and be done.

And actually there is more faster vorbis decoder library than tremor for ARM. It's called [tremolo](http://wss.co.uk/pinknoise/tremolo/). It's latest version is also BSD-like and it really works faster than tremor.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused between SoundTouch and Tremor. Doing a lot of things at once right now. My original question still stands.