# Cross Compiling host target and build

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference of `./configure` option `--build`, `--host` and `--target`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target)

This is related to [What's the difference of `./configure` option `--build`, `--host` and `--target`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target). I haven't understood the difference between host and target. So am asking this with an example.
 I am trying to build some code on my PC. I am guessing it will be i686-pc-linux.  I want to run the code on a mipsel based platform. I have the toolchain for that platform (mipsel-linux-gcc etc) 
What should I be giving as values to host, build and target.

Please don't close as duplicate unless it is of a question which explains this with an example :-)
I have already read the GCC documentation and am still puzzled to be honest

Comment: This isn't really a new question, it should be a comment on the one you linked to.

Comment: The question I linked to which this question has become a duplicate of, is  answered from the GCC documentation which I had read before asking this question. I asked this question to get an example of how to setup the configure option. I don't believe this is a duplicate and hope this question doesn't get deleted. It serves as a handy reference for me( and at least one other person) :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And I found an answer after posting this question.. Still posting it here incase it helps someone else in the future.
http://jingfenghanmax.blogspot.in/2010/09/configure-with-host-target-and-build.html
As per this blog in my case
build will be i686-pc-linux-gnu   ( My PC)
host will be mipsel-linux         ( The platform I am going to run my code on)
target will be used if I am building a cross-compiling toolchain.
Since I am not building a toolchain, I didnt have to specify target.