# Importing .dylib or .la files into iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, cross-compiling, unixodbc

After reading [this awesome post by Tristan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424846/cross-compiling-freetds-to-iphone), where he compiled FreeTDS for use in iOS, I attempted to compile [UnixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) for use in iOS. I was able to get it to compile, which is great.

However, when I compiled FreeTDS, I had a **.a** file that I was able to easily bring into XCode (along with a few **.h** files). This time, the compiler didn't produce a **.a** file. Instead, it produced a **.la** and a **.dylib** file. So far, I have not been able to use these files in my iOS project.

If I could accomplish any of the following, I think my problems would be solved:
    1. Re-compile UnixODBC so that it produces a **.a** file, or
    2. Convert either the **.la** or **.dylib** to a **.a** file, or
    3. Import either the **.la** or **.dylib** to my project, so I can use it in the same way I would use a **.a** file.

So far, I am clueless as to how I would do any of these things (or if it's even possible). Can anybody please help me out?

Thank you!

-Rob

Answer (score 1):

`.dylib` files are dynamically linked libraries, whereas `.a` files are statically linked ones (just google these two expressions). `.la` files are irrelevant now, they're not essential, and they don't contain any code,

If the `configure` script of UnixODBC supports it, you can specify the `--enable-static --disable-shared` options to enable building an .a archive and not a dylib. If the configure script doesn't accept these flags, then you can just go ahead a compile the source files (it will be done by configure), then instead of taking the resulting dylib, use the `ar` command to put the `.o` object files together to form a static archive.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like it will fix my issue. I'll try this out and report back if it worked.