# How to determine proper input for autoconf's system type --build configure option?

Tags: gnu, autoconf

In CPython there is a configuration option for the build machine's system type

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
$ tar -xzvf Python-3.7.3.tgz
$ cd Python-3.7.3
$ ./configure --help | grep -A 3 "System types"
System types:
 --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
 --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
 --target=TARGET   configure for building compilers for TARGET [HOST]
```

How does one properly determine what `BUILD` should be here for any Linux distribution? Through searching I found [CPython Issue 3754 (cross-compilation support for python build)](https://bugs.python.org/issue3754) I can see that valid `BUILD` values are `--build=x86_64-linux-gnu` and `--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu`. I can also see from the [CPython Dockerfile for Python 3.7](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/65b5603fdf177c6d90df6ea6f3bd6e23839c63a4/3.7/stretch/Dockerfile#L39) that `--build` is being set to the output of `$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)`, which on Debian stretch gives

```
$ docker run --rm debian:stretch /bin/bash -c "echo '$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)'"
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

but if I am on something like CentOS 7 then how would I properly determine this using OS commands?

Ideally what I would like is some documentation that better describes the `--build` option. So if this is known and can be linked to that would sufficiently answer the question.

**Edit:** [Thanks to Anthony Shaw I learned](https://twitter.com/anthonypjshaw/status/1129965620383010816) that this is not a CPython issue but related to autoconf. From this information given to me, I see in the [autoconf manual (Section 16.7 Specifying the System Type)](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/System-Type.html#System-Type) that

> ...give it the `--build=type` option. `type` can either be a short name for the system type, such as ‘sun4’, or a canonical name which has the form:
>
> ```
> cpu-company-system
> ```
>
> where system can have one of these forms:
>
> ```
> os
> kernel-os
> ```
>
> See the file `config.sub` for the possible values of each field. If `config.sub` isn't included in this package, then this package doesn't need to know the machine type.

CPython has a `config.sub`

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
$ tar -xzvf Python-3.7.3.tgz
$ cd Python-3.7.3
$ ./config.sub --help
Usage: ./config.sub [OPTION] CPU-MFR-OPSYS or ALIAS

Canonicalize a configuration name.

Options:
  -h, --help         print this help, then exit
  -t, --time-stamp   print date of last modification, then exit
  -v, --version      print version number, then exit

Report bugs and patches to <config-patches@gnu.org>.
```

but it still isn't very clear to me if there is a general Linux wide solution to determining with OS commands how to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what my question was it seems that from [The GNU configure and build system documentation](https://airs.com/ian/configure/)'s section on [Configuration Names](https://airs.com/ian/configure/configure_4.html#SEC27) that what I'm describing when I ask for "[Linux] OS commands" is basically what `config.guess` already provides:

> The shell script `config.guess` will normally print the correct configuration name for the system on which it is run. It does by running `uname` and by examining other characteristics of the system.
>
> Because `config.guess` can normally determine the configuration name for a machine, it is normally only necessary to specify a configuration name when building a cross-compiler or when building using a cross-compiler.

So the answer to my question appears to be that `configure` already supports what I wanted to do, and by trying to pass in `--build` information when I'm building on the same machine as I will be running I'm not helping things if I'm trying to write a Shell script to automate the configure and build process.

The question [What's the difference of “./configure” option “--build”, “--host” and “--target”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target?rq=1) was helpful in coming to this conclusion.