# How to compile autotools project on ubuntu with mingw64? It compiles just fine on Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, mingw-w64

I have C/C++ program with an autoconf-based build system. It compiles for Windows just fine on Fedora (FC36) using the command `mingw64-configure` to configure the autoconf system.

Ubuntu's mingw64 system appears less well developed than Fedora's. It has lots of mingw64 packages, but I can't figure out how to get it to compile. I've tried various `--host` incantations but that frequently doesn't work: I get errors that libraries are not installed.

So what is the correct `./configure` command to get MinGW to compile on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you don't have mingw-w64 versions of the dependency libraries, than the errors you get make sense. You will need to install or build these too. And your Linux package manager won't be able to help you with that.

Comment: That's okay. What is the correct `./configure` command to use?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your `./configure` command on condition you have the prerequisites available for the same target platform. You may need to add `-I` flags in `CFLAGS` (and CXXFLAGS if using C++) and `-L` flags to `LDFLAGS` to point to the locations of the include files and library files of those dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is:

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

See [What's the difference of "./configure" option "--build", "--host" and "--target"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target)

See also [C++ mutex in namespace std does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type)